# Prove that $\forall x\subseteq M, \exists y\in M (x\subseteq y)$

Tags: set-theory

Let $M$ be a transitive proper class satisfying ZF. Prove that
$$\forall x \subseteq M\exists y \in M(x \subseteq y).$$

In the homework there is a hint: if $x$ is a set and $M$ is a proper class, then the elements of $x$ have bounded rank in the sense of $M$.

I don't know why this helps in the proof. I'm really stuck. Any hint, please?

Comment: Hint: the $Y$ you are looking for is of the form $(V_\alpha)^M$ (that is, $M \models Y = V_\alpha$). Combine this hint with the one you’ve been given.